# navigation checkbox drawer in android studio

Tags: android

can someone please help me to make a navigation checkbox drawer in android studio Similar to the picture? i have tried for so long time. I can make a listview as a regular list, but want it to filter alternatives in a different way

[navigation checkbox drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dHyR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your menu and it will help.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_switch"
        android:title="Switch"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
    />
```